# vb script to trigger class onclick event with no ID or Value on web page

Tags: events, button, onclick

what Im trying to do is very simple.  A GPO that runs a cloud-based install once. I just cannot find the correct VB syntax to simply click on a button on a webpage that starts an installation.  I have a runonce batch file in a GPO that calls the vbs file which currently contains...

```js
Sub test()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://xxxxxxx.com"

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            WScript.Sleep 50
        Loop

        Set oInputs = .Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each elm In oInput
            If elm.Value = "the HTML has no valued or ID" Then
                elm.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            WScript.Sleep 50
        Loop

        End With

End Sub
```

The HTML element i am trying to trigger is...

```html
<a class="button" onclick="DownloadSubmit();" href="" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: the only thing that does work is that the page opens in IE upon login and sits there.

Comment: i used the following and got closer where it does open a new tab to a Blank page as indicated by the target value, but the onclick value of DownloadSubmit does not execute...

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button").Item().Click